# Are const and & ignored in std::function?

Tags: c++, c++11

Why does this code compile?

```
std::function<void(const int&)> f = [](int a)
{

};
```

Aren't `int` and `const int&` different types?

Comment: `f` can easily forward a const reference to the lambda, so it's valid. Try defining a function that accepts a const reference and forward it to a function that accepts an `int` like your lambda. It works, right? So, why shouldn't it work in this case?

Comment: A gentleman with a rather handsome beard named Arthur O'Dwyer gave a talk at CppCon 2016 on templates and template type deduction which is available on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vwrXHznaYLA

Answer (score 20, accepted):

They are different, but it does not matter, because `const int&` argument can be passed to `int` parameter, and that is all that is required.

Answer (score 16):

The reason for your code to work is that the templated constructor of `std::function<R(Args...)>` taking an arbitrary function object `F` requires `F` to be callable with `Args...` returning `R`.

> ```
> template<class R, class... ArgTypes> 
> class function<R(ArgTypes...)> { 
>     template<class F> function(F f); 
> };
> ```
>
> Requires: `F` shall be *CopyConstructible*. **f shall be *Callable* for argument types `ArgTypes` and return type `R`**. [...]

A function object taking `int` is callable using `const int&` and thus this code is valid and meets the requirements since both return `void`.